# Excel VBA - Making a Named Range based on a found cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to figure out how to make a named range, based on a cell found using:

```
    For Each Cell In ISBN_Range
            If Cell.Value = ISBN Then
                ISBN_Valid = True
                ISBN_Found = Range("A" & Cell.RowIndex & ":E" & Cell.RowIndex)
                ISBN_Found.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                Exit For
            End If
        Next Cell
```

This is not working, and I am not sure why, I haven't been able to find the answer elsewhere, sorry if this is really simple! I basically just want to make the row of data that the found cell exists in a named range. ISBN_Found is declared as a range much earlier in my code, so that is not the issue.

Comment: Please define "not working".  What error?  on which line?  Also, are all/any of these variables declared?

Comment: It gives me an error that says: 

Run-time Error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method

And highlighed the ISBN_Found = Range code, all variables are declared, ISBN_Found is declared as a range

Comment: There are many things *'not working'* in this code. WOE are you trying to do?

Comment: This is just a small portion of the whole code, everything else is working fine, just the line that says ISBN_Found = Range line doesn't work, I am trying to take the row that where the cell is found, and turn that into a range

Comment: `SET ISBN_Found = Range`

Comment: Set ISBN_Found = Range("A" & Cell.RowIndex & ":E" & Cell.RowIndex) did not work for me, I am still getting the same error

Comment: I figured it out, all I needed to do was delete "Index" in Cell.RowIndex, thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer with some help from the guys in the comments, final code looks like this:

```
For Each Cell In ISBN_Range
            If Cell.Value = ISBN Then
                ISBN_Valid = True
                Set ISBN_Found = Range("A" & Cell.Row & ":E" & Cell.Row) 
                ISBN_Found.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 
                Exit For
            End If
        Next Cell
```

Just needed to delete "Index" from "Cell.RowIndex"